# Validating entities before modifications in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to be able to validate some business rules on entities before any modification to DB is performed (Create, Update, Delete), and throw exception and rollback if these rules fail. I am building a framework and I want to do that always, despite whether user use my class to modify entities or directly NHibernate Session. I also need to be able to customize these business rules, depending on configuration file.

I've tried to inherit `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener`, overriding `PerformSaveOrUpdate`, `PerformUpdate`, `PerformSaveOrReplicate`, `PerformSave`, `OnSaveOrUpdate` and `DefaultSaveEventListener` with overriding `PerformSaveOrUpdate`, `PerformSave`, `PerformSaveOrReplicate`, `PerformUpdate`, `OnSaveOrUpdate`. I just put `Debug.WriteLine`, and called the base implementation. I didn't find any good and detailed description of those, so I tried everything that seems like what I need.

And I have initialized them like this:

```
configuration.EventListeners.SaveOrUpdateEventListeners[0] = new SaveOrUpdatePermissionListener(_mappingContext);
configuration.EventListeners.SaveEventListeners[0] = new SavePermissionListener(_mappingContext);
```

But looks like this does not always work. If I modify objects in the object tree, for some reason these methods catch all objects except of the root object.

What I did wrong? Maybe there are better ways of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do that, by inheriting `IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreDeleteEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener` interfaces instead of `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener` and `DefaultSaveEventListener`.

Still, if anybody has a better idea of achieving the task, I'm eager to listen.

Comment: Found a webpost for this, if it helps: http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2015/04/13/using-nhibernate-eventlisteners-to-validate-and-audit-data/